# Is there a way to create an array of buttons so you can write a generalized code

Tags: c#, arrays, button

I am pretty much new to `C#` programming, I am making a Keyboard in my windows application, I am using a text box as a display so each button will have a separate letter and clicking on each button will type into the textbox. so there will be like 50 buttons on my application. Is there a way to create a KeyPad with more buttons, so I can create an array of buttons so that I might be able to write a generalized code? 
 Is this even possible to write generalized code for 100's of buttons? 
or I'll have to edit each `button_click` function separately?

Thanks!!

I have place buttons separately and I realized that it will take a lot of time .... also I am open to any new suggestions or even a whole new approach towards this problem...

Comment: If all the code is supposed to do it add the letter on display of the Buttons it can be the same for all Buttons, ie __you can hook them all up to the same click handler__. It would cast `sender` to `Button` and then e.g. append its Text to the textbox.Text.. You can also create all buttons dynamically if you know the way you want to lay them out..

Comment: How can I hook them all on the same click handler :/  each button will have its own click handler  .. i didn't understand completely

Comment: If the buttons are created by hand you can do it in the events pane. If not the accepted answer shows how to do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example with a screen containing 2 buttons (a and b). You can register all the buttons to the same click event instead of doing each one individually.

[image]

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //loop through all the buttons and assign to btnClick
            var c = GetAll(this, typeof(Button));

            foreach (var item in c)
            {
                item.Click += btnClick;
            }
        }

        private void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //The sender is a Button so you find the text and append it to your textbox/output
            txtOutput.Text += ((sender as Button).Text);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control, Type type)
        {
            var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

            return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl, type))
                                      .Concat(controls)
                                      .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps in guiding you in the right direction.